# Problem with rich text and how it updates on the screen in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For my game, I wish to have a dialogue system where some words in the dialogue are colored differently. Right now, I have my normal white text being typed to the screen using the .ToCharArray command. This allows me to type one letter at a time to my screen. I've also looked and found something called Rich Text and Markup, which allows me to color my text with different colors while leaving the rest white. The issue is, the sentence is being typed and then updated in the ui to show the color, so for a brief second,  are shown until the text changes green. Is there any way to make it so the text is typed with the color in effect? is there an asset that lets me change colors of certain words in unity? Any help would be appreciated!

Inside the DataBlock Scriptable object, ive typed the sentance i want into the text area. I then put  and  around the word I wanted to change. This caused the TypeSentance Coroutine to type out the sentance pulled from the scriptable object. This also made it so the TypeSentance Coroutine to print out the  and  around the text before updating a second later.

#### First Script

```
public class DataBlock : ScriptableObject
{
    [Tooltip("Please Put Body Text In Here")]
    [SerializeField] [TextArea(3, 10)] string bodyText;

    public string getBodyText()
    {
        return bodyText;
    }
}
```

#### Second Script

```
public class GameCode : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] DataBlock[] DataBlocks;
int currentDataBlock = 0;

private void update()
{
   updateGraphic()
}

public void updateGraphic()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(TypeSentance(DataBlocks
[currentDataBlock].getBodyText()));

        currentDataBlock++

}

IEnumerator TypeSentance(string sentance)
    {
        bodyTextBox.text = "";
        foreach (char letter in sentance.ToCharArray())
        {
            bodyTextBox.text += letter;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.001f);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the result to be that the text is outputted in the color of my choice, but instead it was printed with the  and  and then updated to show the color

Answer (score 1):

Your description is not clear as you are missing some characters and don't give your example `bodyText`. Also it is not clear wich UI component you use.

Nevertheless I assume you are setting invalid tags as text as you iterate through your string. You find more about supported RichtText in [Unity's documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html).

Example:

- This text works fine:
  `"This text is <color=green>green</color> and <color=red>red</color>"`
- This text is missing a closing `</color>`-tag and wont be parsed as `RichText` by the `UI.Text` component:
  `"This text is <color=green>gree`

To resolve this, you can parse the text (every time you extract a part) and check if you are missing a closing tag. If a tag is missing, you just add it at the end.
Also you have to ignore start-tags.

#### There are more things wrong with your code

1. Update must be written uppercase. Otherwise it is not called by Unity. But i guess are you calling it yourself from somewhere else? Than it is very misleading and should be renamed.

   ```
   private void Update()
   {
      updateGraphic()
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating correctly but a frame is showing the text full white, you only need to update the text while the object is off (`gameObject.SetActive(false)`) and then turn it off to apply the change on the very first frame `gameObject.SetActive(true)`.